# Why is my simple program crashing on a break statement?

Tags: c, crash, switch-statement, break

This program is crashing exactly on the break statement of case '2'. There's nothing much to it, it executes the code for that case fine, but it crashes on the break statement, which is really weird, the program should just resume the loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

#define nullptr ((void*)0)

typedef unsigned char byte;         //Tipo numérico de 8 bits
#define max 255
#define cap 256

typedef struct Elemento Elemento;
struct Elemento {

    char* valor;
    byte prioridade;
    bool isvalid;

};

typedef struct {

    short comprimento;
    Elemento elementos[cap];

} Lista;

void inicializa (Lista* q) {        //1

    q->comprimento = 0;

}

void ordena (Lista *q) {

    short i;
    for (i = 1; i < q->comprimento; i ++) {

        Elemento e = q->elementos[i];

        short j;
        for (j = i - 1;
            j >= 0 && q->elementos[j].prioridade < e.prioridade;
            j --) {

            strcpy(q->elementos[j + 1].valor, q->elementos[j].valor);
            q->elementos[j + 1].prioridade = q->elementos[j].prioridade;

        }

        q->elementos[j + 1] = e;

    }

}

void enfileira (Lista* q, Elemento *s, byte p) {      //2

    if (q->comprimento != cap) {
        
        q->elementos[q->comprimento].valor = (char *) malloc(strlen(s->valor)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(q->elementos[q->comprimento].valor, s->valor);
        q->elementos[q->comprimento].prioridade = p;
        q->elementos[q->comprimento].isvalid = true;
 
        q->comprimento ++;

        if (q->comprimento > 1) ordena(q);

    }

}

Elemento primeiro (Lista* q) {     //3

    Elemento e;
    if (q->comprimento != 0) {

        e.isvalid = true;
        strcpy(e.valor, q->elementos[0].valor);
        return e;
    }

    e.isvalid = false;
    return e;
}

Elemento remova (Lista* q) {       //4

    Elemento e;
    if (q->comprimento != 0) {

        e.isvalid = true;
        strcpy(e.valor, q->elementos[0].valor);

        byte i;
        for (i = 0; i < q->comprimento - 1; i ++) {

            strcpy(q->elementos[i].valor, q->elementos[i + 1].valor);
            q->elementos[i].prioridade = q->elementos[i + 1].prioridade;

        }

        q->comprimento --;

        return e;
    }

    e.isvalid = false;
    return e;
}

short comprimento (Lista* q) {       //5

    return q->comprimento;
}

void reinicializa (Lista* q) {      //6

    q->comprimento = 0;

}

void finaliza (Lista* q) {      //7


}

int main () {

    Lista s;
    Elemento e; e.valor = nullptr;
    char *string = nullptr;
    float valor;
    byte prioridade;
    short buffer_tam, string_tam;

    byte input;
    do {

        printf("operacao: ");
        string_tam = getline(&string, &buffer_tam, stdin);

        switch (string[0]) {
        
            case '1':
                
                inicializa(&s);
                break;
            
            case '2':
            
                string_tam = getline(&e.valor, &buffer_tam, stdin);
                e.valor[string_tam - 1] = '\0';
                scanf("%hhu", &prioridade);
                enfileira(&s, &e, prioridade);
                break;

            case '3':

                printf("%s\n", primeiro(&s).valor);
                break;

            case '4':

                printf("%s\n", remova(&s).valor);
                break;

            case '5':

                printf("%hi\n", comprimento(&s));
                break;

            case '6':

                reinicializa(&s);
                break;

            case '7':

                finaliza(&s);
                break;
        }

    } while (string[0] != '0');

    return 0;
}
```

Maybe it's not reproducible elsewhere, so maybe there's a common reason for this to happen, but I didn't find anything on this subject googling.

Solution: The same thing happened when I replaced the switch with 'if' statements, it would crash whenever it left the if environment. And the cause of that was the mixing of getline and scanf, I replaced the scanf with another getline in case '2' and it didn't crash.

Comment: How do you know it crashes on the break statement?

Comment: How does `string_tam - 1` make any sense? Why not `string_tam`? What if getline returns -1?

Comment: It crashes on the break statement because I've put breakpoints on it, and it crashes exactly after that break, really weird.

Comment: I haven't checked getline return possibilities, I'll check it out, thanks.

Comment: "*the cause of that was the mixing of getline and scanf*" ... don't ever mix those two!!! Always use exclusively `fgets()` (or POSIX `getline()`) [with maybe an occasional `getchar()` here and there] for user input :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not enough space

> ```
>        q->elementos[q->comprimento].valor = (char *) malloc(strlen(s->valor)*sizeof(char));
>        strcpy(q->elementos[q->comprimento].valor, s->valor);
> ```

Allocate 1 more byte for the `'\0'` string terminator.

Also, the cast for the return value of `malloc()` is, at best, redundant and `sizeof (char)` is `1` by definition:

```
   q->elementos[q->comprimento].valor = malloc(strlen(s->valor) + 1);
   strcpy(q->elementos[q->comprimento].valor, s->valor);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just corrected this now. Still crashing on that second break statement though.